# Consecutive prime powers $p^m<q^n$ such that $q^n-p^m=11$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, computational-mathematics, conjectures

Define two prime powers $p^m<q^n$, ($m,n\in\mathbb N$) to be consecutive if it doesn't exist a prime power $r^k$ such that $p^m\!<r^k\!<q^n$. It seems that every even number is the difference between two consecutive prime powers, I haven't ran any large tests yet, but what about the odd numbers?

> Are there two consecutive prime powers $p^m<q^n$ and $i\in\mathbb N^+$ such that $q^n-p^m=11^i$?

I have tested all consecutive prime powers less than $10,000,000$ without finding any solution to $q^n-p^m=11^i$.

(A pattern seems to suggest that no odd numbers $N\ge 31$ have a solution to $q^n-p^m=N$, consecutive prime powers. But this must be wrong since prime powers has similar asymptotic distribution as the primes).

Comment: This is a good question.  But "power", not "potency", is the usual word in English. I've edited accordingly.

Comment: @MichaelLugo, thanks!

Comment: So one of the primes has to be even, and there are few of those.

Comment: Also, all prime powers are odd except for the powers of two. So any odd difference will have either $p = 2$ or $q = 2$.

Comment: If
$q^n-p^m=11^i
$,
then either $p$ or $q$ must be $2$.

Comment: @hardmath: there are two cases, $2^n-p^m=11$ and $q^n-2^m=11$, in one question then. :)

Comment: For powers of $11$ greater than the first we get into the realm of the abc-conjecture.

Comment: Note that $p^1 - 2^n = 78557$ has no solutions.  It seems plausible that one could extend the argument to prime powers rather than just primes.

Comment: 'No odd numbers $N\geq 31$ have a solution to $q^n-p^m=N$' is almost certainly false heuristically; near $2^k$ the probability that the next $N$ numbers are composite is approximately $(1-\frac{\ln 2}k)^{N/2}$ and for all $N$ this is bounded away from zero for large $k$, so we should in fact expect infinitely many powers of $2$ whose nearest prime is $\geq N$ away from them.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki, I suppose you are right, but it takes very big prime powers to produce those odd differences.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

See the OEIS: https://oeis.org/A013603 gives the difference between $2^n$ and the largest prime less than $2^n$. We can read off that:

- $2^n - 11$ is prime and there are no primes between it and $2^{n}$ for $n = 42, 78, 114, 190, 322, 546, 3894$.
- $2^n - 11^2$ is prime and there are no primes between it and $2^n$ for $n = 219, 303, 1443, 2333, 2589, 3315, 3693$.
- $2^n - 11^3$ is prime and there are no primes between it and $2^n$ for $n = 1390, 1670$.

These are the only examples where $n < 5000$ and $q = 2$. The "mirror image" sequence of the gap between $2^m$ and the smallest prime greater than $2^m$, which doesn't exist in OEIS, would be needed for the $p = 2$ case.

Comment: For example, $139-2^7=11$, but $137$ was already prime, and thus these prime powers are not *consecutive*.

Comment: See [OEIS A013597](https://oeis.org/A013597) for something of a "mirror image" sequence of  `a(n) = nextprime(2^n) - 2^n.`